# AngularJS and JAX-RS with ng-Grid

Tags: angularjs, jax-rs, ng-grid

I am working on a AngularJS & JAX-RS application.(frankly am new to both)

On UI i have a ng-grid , each row has 3 columns , 1st a check box , 2nd Name , 3rd Age.

User can select rows from grid and click on **"export to excel"**.
I am posting the whole data when user clicks on export to excel button

```
@POST
@PATH("/xlsExport")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response excelExport(MultiPartFormData mfd) throws Exception {
        System.out.ptrintln(mfd); // code not reaching here
}
```

Am getting exception "RESTEASY003065 : Cannot Consume Contet Type"
UI looks like

Also Tried

```
   @POST
    @PATH("/xlsExport")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response excelExport(String mfd) throws Exception {
            System.out.ptrintln(mfd); // code not reaching here
    }
```

Same error

Also Tried

```
   @POST
    @PATH("/xlsExport")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response excelExport(String mfd) throws Exception {
            System.out.ptrintln(mfd); // incorrect values shown
    }
```

This didn't give error, but also didn't give me all rows, just gives some incorrect values in  ....  so if i select 3 rows of 10 , i get some incorrect values in String as of now

Also Tried

```
   @POST
    @PATH("/xlsExport")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
    public Response excelExport(@FormParam("id") Sting id) throws Exception {
            System.out.ptrintln(id); // Compile time error
    }
```

Same error

```
<form novalidate name="someForm" method="POST" action="/xlsExport">
    ...
    <div class="ngHeaderContainer">
        <div> <input class="ngSelectoionHeader" .../> </div> <!-- checkbox -->
        <div> Name </div> 
        <div> Age </div> 
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" value="Export">
</form>
```

Will appreciate if can get some help

1. How can i resolve the error
2. Is this the best way to do it , cant i consume data in JSON

Comment: In order to send JSON (you're currently sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but who knows what the data looks like), you will need to handle the form submit event in your front-end app (ie, remove the `action` attribute and use `ng-submit`) then use `$http` or similar to post the data

Comment: Thanks for your help , was able to do it by ng-submit ... I dont see an option to accept comment as ans.... may be if you can repost the same as a answer , will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send JSON (you're currently sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but who knows what the plain HTML data looks like), you will need to handle the form submit event in your front-end app.

To do this, remove the `action` attribute and use `ng-submit` to call a controller function which uses `$http` or similar to post the data...

```
<form novalidate name="someForm" ng-submit="submit()">
```

and something like this in your controller

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $http.post('/xlsExport', $scope.someDataModel).then(res => {
        // handle the response here
    });
};
```